# Verilog assign result of module

Tags: verilog, quartus

I am trying to take the result of a module and assign it to an input of another module, however I keep getting an error about declaring net types. I feel like I'm missing part of the syntax rules here, but I've been unable to find a solution. Any help much appreciated!

Some nonsense code to demonstrate:

```
module m1(SW, LED);
  input SW;
  output LED;
  reg [3:0] out;
  reg [1:0] x;

  assign x = out[1:0];
  moduleA mA(.in(SW), .out(out));
  moduleA mB(.in(x), .out(LED));
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, your problem is declaring `x` and `out` as register type.

When you assign to something in an `assign` statement, or by connecting it to an output port of a module instance, you need to declare it as a wire instead of a reg.

I'd also add that your `out` variable is redundant. You can use one variable to connect to the output of one module and the input of the other:

```
   wire [1:0] x;

   moduleA mA(.in(SW), .out(x));
   moduleA mB(.in(x), .out(LED));
```

Saves you declaring and keeping track of an extra variable and an extra assign statement.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** assign to a **reg**ister using the `assign` keyword

You **can** however assign to a **wire**.

```
wire [1:0] x;
assign x = out[1:0];
```

But it is possible to asynchronously assign within an always block (i.e. without a clock) to a register:

```
reg [1:0] x;
always @ * begin
    x <= out[1:0];
end
```

---

Two simple rules about net types:

- `wire` = `assign`
- `reg` = `always` (and/or `initial`)

Answer (score 0):

The crucial point you're missing is the difference between **net** types and **variable** types.

**net** is a connection wire, usually this is keyword **wire** but there are other net types for tristate, wired-or, wire-and, and a few other exotic cases. You use net types for structural description.

**variable** is "temporary storage of programming data", usually this is keyword **reg** but could also be **integer** or **real** in a test bench. Often **reg** ends up being synthesized with a D-flip-flop register, but not always.

A useful resource is Sutherland HDL's [Verilog HDL Quick Reference Guide](http://sutherland-hdl.com/pdfs/verilog_2001_ref_guide.pdf)